# Python Script in GIS Project

Tags: python, gis, arcgis

I'm a student in a GIS Programming course.  My professor did not inform me before registering that Python experience would be useful.  I have no experience with Python and need help on this project.  Any examples or clear explanations would be great.  Here is the project:

Make a copy of the FirDepartment.gdb file geodatabase at \cartggp\Geo573&673_Lab\Lab5_Part2
to your computer. Write a python stand-alone script
to get a count of all the single-family homes and multifamily structures in each of the 44
fire response zones: (100 points)

1) Each fire response zone has a corresponding feature class in the database with
name structure “FireBoxMap_id”. There is also a building footprint feature class,
BldgFoorprints, with a use code field named UseCode (1=single-family,
2=multi- family)

2) First of all, you need to use ListFeatureClasses to create a list object that contains
all the “FireBoxMap_id” feature classes. Then use a for loop structure to go over
each zone.

3) In the for loop structure for each zone feature class, you need to write codes to
add two new fields to have the counts of single-family and multi-family
buildings. (check the use of AddField geoprocessing tool)

4) Then select all the single-family buildings that are within the zone, get the count,
assign the count to one the two new field for single-family counts; and then
select all the multi-family buildings that are within the zone, get the count, assign
the count to the other new field for multi-family counts. (check the use of
CalculateField geoprocessing tool)

5) Tools you may need:
AddFieldDelimiters for the where_clause
MakeFeatureLayer (set the where_clause to only retrieve only single-family or
multi-family buildings.
SelectLayerByLocation (use “HAVE_THEIR_CENTER_IN” option)
GetCount

Here's what I have on step 2 so far:

```
import arcpy
import os
arcpy.env.workspace = "D:\Fehr10\Fehr_Python\Datapdf\FireDepartment.gdb"
featureclasses = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()
```

It's not much.  I based this off of an example in GIS's help database.

Comment: You're asking a few different questions here. You should consider splitting it into multiple questions like "How to get the count of features using arcpy?", "How to calculate a field using arcpy?" and "How to select features using arcpy?" Once you do this, you'll realize that your problem is much simpler and these questions all have easy answers in the arcpy documentation and on http://gis.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly to install an ArcGIS desktop(trial license is required);
The link to get trial license is as below:
[arcgis trial license](http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/arcgis-for-desktop/free-trial)

Secondly, click help of ArcGIS desktop to go through the help document of arcPy.
As the screenshot below:
[image: arcpy help in ArcGIS desktop]
Other help documents for python is necessary either.